# Why is a variable able to be defined after definition of function using it?

Tags: python, list, function, data-structures, arguments

I have a very simple and maybe dumb question:

Why does this work?

```
def print_list():
    for student in student_list:
        print(student)

student_list = ["Simon", "Mal", "River", "Zoe", "Jane", "Kaylee", "Hoban"]
print_list()
```

The way I've come to know functions and arguments, the function `print_list()` shouldn't recognize `student_list` since I didn't assign it as an argument for the function.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the really impressive and informative answered. I will go read a bit more about the Global scope, although I understand it from your definitions. I am not sure however that I completely agree with how my question wad edited. I understand perfectly that on the sequence og code execution, the list assignment occurs before the function is called, hence it makes sense to me that since Python knows to look for variables in the Global Scope it can use what was defined in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, variables are created when you *assign* them.  In your case, `student_list` is assigned in the global scope, so it is a global variable.  (The global scope is the stuff that isn't inside your function.)

When Python encounters a variable inside a function that is not a local variable (that is, it was not passed in as an argument and was not assigned inside the function), it automatically looks for the variable in the global scope.

If you are wondering what the purpose of the `global` statement is, since global variables are already visible inside functions:  `global` allows you to *reassign* a global variable, and have it take effect globally.  For example:

```
def b():
    global a
    a = 5

a = 4
print(a)  # prints 4
b()
print(a)  # prints 5
```

In most cases, you don't need the `global` statement, and I would recommend that you don't use it, especially until you are much more experienced in Python.  (Even experienced Python programmers tend not to use `global` very much, though.)

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Thanks John! I did learn about the Global statement in the context that you are suggesting. And I also understand why it not recommended (messy to debug, unexpected outcomes, no single source of control and change for the value etc...). What I didn't know is the existence of the term Global Scope (if not in function and not in class).

Answer (score 6):

By the time you're calling `print_list()`, you have `student_list` defined as a global variable.

Comment: Wow, you're quick! Thanks for this reply. Two question then now come to mind:
1. Why is my list defined as a Global Variable? I thought I have to use the Global Statement.
2. What is than the difference between the code above and this code?
def print_list(List):
    for i in List:
        print(i)
        
student_list = ["Simon", "Mal", "River", "Zoe", "Jane", "Kaylee", "Hoban"]
print_list(student_list)

Comment: It is due to python's scoping behaviour.  To understand this behaviour, you can read the relevant section of the tutorial here -> http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces

Comment: 1. Python goes kine by line and builds the program structure. You could say that everything not indented is global. You have a function declaration, a list and a function call. The function call actually executes your function, but you can say it's the same as the others from this point of view (or what @wim just said).

Comment: 2. the outcome should be the same, only difference is that in your original code you were relying on scope and in the new variant you're doing it with parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand it is that your program has 3 parts

1. define print_list()
2. initialise student_list (global variable)
3. call print_list()

When you call print_list(), student_list is already there. Also, in a function you have the scopes where a variable (student_list) is searched:
 1. local scope (it'll fail because you don't have it defined, only referred)
 2. global scope (it'll succeed, because it was just initialised

Comment: I am confused! :) I learned that a function needs to receive arguments from the program, otherwise it won't recognize them when they are referred within the function. Is it possible that I am confused, and that it's just good practice to separate the two? Is this true for most programming languages?

Comment: Heh, the "needs to receive an arg .. otherwise" is not accurate. There is a concept of scope in all modern languages - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science) . It basically says that when a variable is referred, the compiler/interpreter tries to find it in the block where it was declared (the function in your case). Failing that, it goes one level up and so on until it finds it.